# Create a custom block with no input or output ports

Tags: python, gnuradio

I would like to create a custom block in GNU Radio which takes two parameters and has **no input or output** ports.

I have read about the block types on GNU Radio but I'm unsure on which will be best suited for my scenario.

The purpose of the block is to add images to the `Top Block` with respect to the data received in it's parameter.

I would like to know what **type of block** I should use for this scenario.

Comment: Shouldn't a signal processing block in GNU Radio have at least one input (sink) or output (source)?

Comment: `wxSlider` widget or other `wxWidget` blocks don't have input or output ports. I'm hoping to achieve something on those lines. It's more of a helper block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GNU Radio's [Block Coding Guide](https://gnuradio.org/redmine/projects/gnuradio/wiki/BlocksCodingGuide) defines Block as -

> A functional processing unit with **inputs** and **outputs**

As you said what you want here is something like a widget. For that just adding an `xml` to `gnuradio/grc/blocks..` and a creating a corresponding `.py` to implement the functionality you want should do, I guess.

**Edit 1:** The `wxWidgets` are implemented in `/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/gnuradio/wxgui/forms/forms.py`. What you want is something very similar, that is, to add something to the Top Block (GUI) (*and it has nothing to do with the signal processing part*). This should get you started!

Comment: Is there a method to install this type of custom blocks?

Comment: In the corresponding python file, what **type of block** should I inherit?

Comment: @SaileshSriram: No type at all. PuRaK is right, what you want to do is *not* a GNU Radio block, but just a graphical Block in the GNU Radio companion. You don't win anything by deriving your class from a GNU Radio signal processing block type if you don't do signal processing.
You'll have to write your own XML file, containing the description of which parameters your block has and which python to execute upon creation. I don't really know what you mean with "add images to a top_block", though.